# ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "react-html-attrs" specified

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, es6-module-loader

I have tried all the way to run sample Module-Loader program based on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_4139363737&feature=iv&src_vid=MhkGQAoc7bc&v=9kJVYpOqcVU) but even after following with all the links in stackoverflow regarding this, am unable to fix the issue.Please find the details of my project below,

**My Project Structure:**
[image]

```
**package.json**
{
  "name": "react-tutorials",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-react-html-attrs": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.16.0",
    "react": "^0.14.6",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.6",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.8.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.12.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-react-html-attrs": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.16.0",
    "react": "^0.14.6",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.6",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.8.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.12.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --content-base src --inline --hot",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**webconfig.js**

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  entry: "./js/scripts.js",
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
          plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-decorators-legacy', 'transform-class-properties'],
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/js",
    filename: "scripts.min.js"
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
  ],
};
```

**Exception trace:**

```
D:\Software\Ping\react-js-tutorials-master\react-js-tutorials-master\1-basic-rea
ct>webpack
Hash: 826e21c818de1882d366
Version: webpack 1.13.2
Time: 1424ms
    + 1 hidden modules

ERROR in ./js/scripts.js
Module build failed: ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "react-html-attrs" specified
 in "base" at 0, attempted to resolve relative to "D:\\Software\\Ping\\react-js-
tutorials-master\\react-js-tutorials-master\\1-basic-react\\js"
    at D:\Software\Ping\react-js-tutorials-master\react-js-tutorials-master\1-ba
sic-react\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager
.js:176:17
    at Array.map (native)
    at Function.normalisePlugins (D:\Software\Ping\react-js-tutorials-master\rea
ct-js-tutorials-master\1-basic-react\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\
file\options\option-manager.js:154:20)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (D:\Software\Ping\react-js-tutorials-master\re
act-js-tutorials-master\1-basic-react\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation
\file\options\option-manager.js:228:36)
    at OptionManager.init (D:\Software\Ping\react-js-tutorials-master\react-js-t
utorials-master\1-basic-react\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\op
tions\option-manager.js:373:12)
    at File.initOptions (D:\Software\Ping\react-js-tutorials-master\react-js-tut
orials-master\1-basic-react\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\inde
x.js:221:65)
    at new File (D:\Software\Ping\react-js-tutorials-master\react-js-tutorials-m
aster\1-basic-react\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:141
:24)
    at Pipeline.transform (D:\Software\Ping\react-js-tutorials-master\react-js-t
utorials-master\1-basic-react\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\pipelin
e.js:46:16)
    at transpile (D:\Software\Ping\react-js-tutorials-master\react-js-tutorials-
master\1-basic-react\node_modules\babel-loader\index.js:38:20)
    at Object.module.exports (D:\Software\Ping\react-js-tutorials-master\react-j
s-tutorials-master\1-basic-react\node_modules\babel-loader\index.js:131:12)
```

Comment: see if https://github.com/insin/babel-plugin-react-html-attrs/blob/master/README.md this helps...

Comment: sunleo, did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 6):

Try npm install babel-plugin-react-html-attrs --save

and while you're at it,
   $npm install babel-plugin-transform-class-properties --save

For some reason the name is shortened in the error message.
These help process attributes and class names from html pasted in as JSX codes.  The syntax needs to be adapted to JSX.

See https://github.com/insin/babel-plugin-react-html-attrs/blob/master/README.md

Oops, now I see these in your package.json (tldr).  Somehow these errors got fixed for me by doing the npm installs.

Answer (score 1):

I cloned the same repository from learnCodeAcademy, and got issues when try run `webpack` , I did the following step by step till i got the `webpack` command ran without any issue.
`npm install webpack --save-dev`
`npm install webpack-dev-server --save-dev`
`npm install babel-loader --save-dev`
`npm install babel-core --save-dev`
`npm install babel-plugin-react-html-attrs --save-dev`
`npm install babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy --save-dev`
`npm install babel-plugin-transform-class-properties --save-dev`
`npm install babel-preset-react --save-dev`
`npm install babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev`
`npm install babel-preset-stage-0 --save-dev`
`npm install react-dom --save-dev`
`npm install react --save-dev`

And when i ran `webpack` command , i got the following result :

Hash: c323a36a23de43f8c0cf
Version: webpack 1.15.0
Time: 2186ms
        Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
client.min.js  1.76 MB       0  [emitted]  main
    + 163 hidden modules

Then you can run it using  `npm run dev`
as on package.json the script mapped as below :

`"dev": "webpack-dev-server --content-base src --inline --hot"`

I also modified the `webpack.config.js` the `entry` section as followed:
  `entry: {`
  `javaScript: './js/client.js',`
   `html: './index.html'`
 `}`

This is the result after running `npm run dev`

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Axbn.png)

I hope this will help, if i answered your question, kindly mark it.
Thanks.